# Merge hourly netcdf files into daily files with cdo and using shell script

Tags: shell, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have the variable:

```
files=$(ls *.nc)
```

Which contain hourly netcdf files that I want to merge into daily files using cdo.
I need to create something like `"cdo merge $files[1] $files[2] .... $files[24] all.nc"` and run the expression. How can I create this expression in shell?

Comment: Do the filenames contain space?

Comment: just to be sure, you want daily files with 24 timesteps, or did you require a daily mean?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, the following might well produce the desired result:

```
cdo merge *.nc all.nc
```

In other words, let shell globbing do the work for you. A shell array variable seems unnecessary. But if you insist on using the array, try this

```
cdo merge "${files[@]}" all.nc
```